# How do I run a simple EJB? I have a simple client, and a simple Session Bean created via Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, ejb

I'm a newbie to Java and to EJB. Want to create a simple EJB.

So I've created an EJB Project via Eclipse (Eclipse Java EE IDE Juno Service Release 1 Build ID: 20120920-0800). Then I've added a Stateless Session Bean there with Remote and Local interfaces. Then I added a simple method that just returns a sum of 2 numbers. Here is the code:

Test.java:

```
package ejb;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class Test
 */
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class Test implements TestRemote, TestLocal {

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public Test() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public int getSum(int a , int b) {
    return (a + b);
}

}
```

TestLocal.java:

```
package ejb;

import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface TestLocal {
    public int getSum(int a , int b);
}
```

TestRemote.java :

```
package ejb;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface TestRemote {
    public int getSum(int a , int b);
}
```

I right-clicked on my EJB Project and exported it as a JAR file. Then I deployed it to GlassFish3 server: 1) Applications - Deploy and so on; 2) JNDI - Custom Resources. I've set Resource Type to `ejb.TestRemote` , Factory Class to `org.glassfish.resources.custom.factory.EjbFactory` . JNDI Name was `Test`. Then I've coded a simple client:

Main.java:

```
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import ejb.TestRemote;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        try {           
            TestRemote testR = (TestRemote) new InitialContext().lookup("Test");
            //System.out.println(new InitialContext().lookup("Test").toString());
            //.toString displays: Reference Class Name: ejb.TestRemote
            System.out.println(testR.getSum(50, 500));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

I've added `gf-client-module.jar` from `C:\glassfish3\glassfish\modules` and a JAR file of my EJB Project to Java Build Path (Project-Properties).

Then I tried to launch my client in Eclipse and got following message appeared immediately:

```
com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.CommonClassLoaderServiceImpl findDerbyClient
INFO: Cannot find javadb client jar file, derby jdbc driver will not be available by default.
```

Then I got next message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.naming.Reference cannot be cast to ejb.TestRemote
at Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

So, can anyone please help me with that?.. I'm really confused: .toString method called on a reference displays that it is a proper ejb.TestRemote class reference, as I mentioned before. But... It doesn't work ((

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**RESOLVED FOR ME, BUT WITH SOME ANOTHER WAY**

I've lost hope to make it with Eclipse and separately installed GlassFish. So, I've installed a GlassFish server to Eclipse, and deployed my EJB project there. It worked: now my Client works fine. The only change was - I should provide a full package name to .lookup: like `.lookup("ejb.TestRemote")`.

Thanks everyone who tried/wanted/wished to help!

Comment: You need to deploy EAR, instead of JAR

Comment: Thanks, but where do I get it?